# In safari browser we can do iPhone / mobile simulation

Tags: iphone, firefox, safari

In safari browser we can do iPhone / mobile simulation. Any one know hw to test the iphone application look and feel in safari / FF browser.

Comment: Are you asking about web apps?

Comment: no my question. How to test HTML5 web page look and feel in safari / FF browser for iphone and ipad application

Comment: Firefox is not available on the iPhone. Are you kidding?

Comment: i am asking some simulator.... this is not joke or fun happing here!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this, have develop enabled on safari, and go down to User Agent, then choose mobile Safari, and you will be able to see how it appear in a mobile browser for iphone, ipod touch, ipad, ect.
[image: like this.]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex... this what I ask... but How to enable develop

Comment: Safari --> Preferences --> Advance --> then there's a box at the bottom. Don't forget to accept answer if it helps.

Comment: @BoltClock: I am not testing you... I am today only statr my iphone app so I am asking all basic question. if you know every then please share the info.... thanks for the comments